# SSH - Permission denied (publickey) for created user

Tags: linux, ubuntu, unix, ssh, ubuntu-16.04

I can ssh to a digitalocean server using:

`ssh root@1.1.1.1` (with the correct IP address)

however, after adding a user:

```
adduser git
...
is this information correct?
Y
...
```

I am not able to SSH with this new user

```
ssh git@1.1.1.1
Permission denied (publickey).
```

Why is my public key correct for `root` but not for `git`?

**Update**

If it matters, I am using digitalocean.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know the problem, what your facing, you need to check the privilege of your key.
Change the user right permission. I do had an identifical problem, I can able to clone git via https not via ssh.

chmod utility will solve your issue:

This command will solve your problem.

```
chmod 777 <id_rsa_key(file)>
```

Some other frequently used examples are:

```
777 anyone can do anything (read, write, or execute)
755 you can do anything; others can only read and execute
711 you can do anything; others can only execute
644 you can read and write; others can only read
```

Comment: Where is the rsa key file located?

Comment: check this path .~/.ssh, you would have saved your public key on your machine. .sometime you might have with extension *.pub, .ssh/id_rsa.pub

Comment: It looks like digitalocean placed an `authorized_keys` file in `~/.ssh` and `/root/.ssh`.  After setting both to `777` (temporarily), I still was not able to ssh using the newly created user.  I have also restarted SSH with `service ssh restart`.

Comment: I have also tried copying over the `authorized_keys` into `/home/git/.ssh` and changed it's permissions to `777`, but still no luck.

Comment: Nevermind, it does work.  After changing the permissions of `authorized_keys` in `/home/git/.ssh`, I was testing with an incorrect IP.

Comment: After making sure the new user owns it's own `authorized_keys`, ssh works with `600` permissions.